# Blender 2.9 Eevee- Materials and textures not showing in render or viewport shading (Update)

Tags: texturing, materials, 3d-view, shaders, eevee-render-engine

(Update: I am NOT using a AMD GPU, so the question that has been answered referring to changing the AMD GPU driver to its previous version does NOT work for me. So now I am reposting the question to get an answer.)

So I am trying to add a shader to my model and when I try to check in the shader viewport or render viewport I just get what looks like a transparent model. I've added different light sources, removed light sources, changed shader nodes, and played with textures and I get nothing. I've searched online but of the results I found, they were either irrelevant to my problem or required a fix that did not work for me particular issue. I really hope someone can help. I'd like to share the file here but I have no idea how so we'll start with screen shots.

[image]

[image]

Comment: deleting and re-posting the same question is not how this site works. Editing  your question so it can be reopened (which it would have been) is how this site works. Now, what is your GPU? Have you updated your drivers lately?

Comment: Sorry I didn't know that. I thought I automatically had to repost the question. My GPU is a NVIDIA Geforce GTX 1060 6GB

Comment: Please don't post the same question more than once. If you feel your previous question was incorrectly [marked as duplicate](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates), or the linked posts don't adequately address your issue, go back to your previous question and edit by pressing the *Edit* button below, including information of what you have tried, why it failed and how the duplicates don't address your issue. Once edited the question is automatically queued up for review so it can be reopened.

Comment: Please read through the [help](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help) for the site, there's some useful information there for users to get familiar with how things work and to best benefit. The [tour] is especially helpful if you have never read through it. Also, new information is usually better as an [edit] so other users see it when they read your question.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Yeah sorry about that. Duly noted.

Comment: @Timaroberts Got it. Thanks for that info. I'll go through the tour asap. Again, my apologies.

Comment: please provide your blend file to we can check it out

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/k7721ijfisehpj9/Tora1.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

I haven't figured out why the issue is happening but have discovered a fix. Its kind of annoying but I opened blender 2.79 and appended the model there. Deleted all materials and textures, saved, then appended the model back into blender 2.9. Everything seems to work fine now.